# Adjective for a thing/place well-known by a minority of people

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What would you call a place or thing that's well-known or renowned but only among a locality, family, or small group? I've looked into it and have failed to find anything that fits.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you intend to use the word?

Comment: It is "locally famous".

Comment: You can put *local* in front of the renowned thing to limit it: *local celebrity, local sensation, local phenomenon, local hero, local personality...*

Comment: It's not one word, but *well-kept secret* is often applied to places like restaurants, when those who frequent the place would like to avoid it becoming too popular and crowded.

Comment: If a small number are addicted to X, X can be a cult favorite, or cult classic.

Comment: You may say that the place is "confidential" (*marked by intimacy or willingness to confide, not notorious*).